# change font in komacv

Tags: fonts, koma-script, komacv

I want to change the font here:

```
\documentclass{komacv}

\begin{document}

\section{M}
\cvitem{M}{M}

\end{document}
```

to be the same as here:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
M
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

In `scrlttr2` it should be `lmodern`. But I'm unable to change the font of `komacv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you are asking to change the font in `komacv` from sans serif to roman, right?

In chapter 3.7 Encoding and Fonts of the `komacv` documentation (call `texdoc komacv` on your terminal!) you can read that the style for a section is defined like:

```
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\sffamily\mdseries\slshape}
```

Just change it to

```
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily\mdseries\slshape}
```

And to get the roman font in normal text you need to add

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}\normalfont
```

at the beginning of your document.

So with the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass{komacv}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily\mdseries\slshape} % <=============

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}\normalfont % <==================

\section{M}
\cvitem{M}{M}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Do not forget to change the other font definitions to use `\rmdefault` ...

Comment: So `\newkomafont{firstnamefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}` would be correct. Can you tell me what the difference between `\rmdefault` and `\rmfamily` is?